# Add submenu in Main Menu bar

Tags: mfc, submenu

I want to add submenu in Main Menu bar in my MFC app
 It has a design as follows,

**Main Menu**

```
 Menu Item1
 Menu Item2
         SubMenuItem1
         SubMenuItem2
         SubMenuItem3 
Menu Item3
```

The sub Menu of Menu item3 must be added progrmatically. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a fairly comprehensive example of how to create MFC menus dynamically [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/menus/mfcdynamenu.aspx). As you'll see it's quite involved.

Alternatively you add the item at design time, but hide it, revealing it and assigning function pointers for click events at runtime as required.